# How can data collation from different sources in Excel file be accomplished?

Tags: database, microsoft-excel-2013, dashboard

I am trying to make a main database Excel file from 5 different colleagues in the same company using Office 2013. The format is going to be same, but how to keep this automatically updated in the Main Excel File.

Will using Power Pivot help?
What should be the right approach to make this work?

Comment: What have you researched and/or tried so far?

Comment: .Hi Charlie, I've one thing in mind, i.e. the manual approach of collating it myself in Main data base, but this is not how it should be. I'm still researching. I'm starting up with SQL Solution, but it will take some time for me to understand. Do you have any suggestions, appreciate you looking into this. Best, Divy

Comment: Please stop using greetings and salutations. They were edited out to avoid clutter. Thank you.

Comment: Oh Sure, understand.

Comment: Have you looked at [linking](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/connect-data-in-another-workbook-to-your-workbook-HA103791160.aspx) to the data in the colleague's workbooks?

Comment: .I've considered that, but not implemented. I would do that, and post the feedback. Charlie, Appreciate this assistance. But would this work to collaborate  and show in a Master Table?

Comment: But would this work to collaborate and show only new records in a Master Table?